# formula that syncs multi-select picklist from accounts to contacts object

Tags: picklist, multi-select

I have a formula that sync multi-select picklist field from accounts to contacts object but having issue on character limit.

Eg.,

```
IF( INCLUDES(Account.Category2__c ,"Accessories (Bags, hats, scarves etc)"),
    "Accessories (Bags, hats, scarves etc)","") 
& 
IF( INCLUDES(Account.Category2__c ,"Accountants & Bookkeepers"),
    "Accountants & Bookkeepers","") 
& 
IF( INCLUDES(Account.Category2__c ,"Activities"), "Activities","")
```

We have a long list of this category2. If i include all the listed category on the formula. It only allows upto the character limit. Is there other way on how to sync multi-select picklist field from accounts to contacts object?

Accessories (Bags, hats, scarves etc)
Accountants & Bookkeepers
Activities
Activities & enrichment
Adult Enrichment
Adventure Holidays
Aesthetics
Afternoon Tea
Airconditioning
etc.....................................................

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can try this : -

1. Create workfolw rule and update the field based on the criteria which you have mentioned in the Formula and in field update , update the desired value.
2. if there you face the same issue then you need do the same update using trigger.